# Publishing a standalone exe file with .Net Core 3.0 and using an app.config

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config

I have a .Net Core 3.0 project and wanted to take advantage of the new option to publish the project as a single .exe file.

I use the command

`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true`

This, sure enough, produces a single .exe file but the problem is I have an app.config file in my project that the users should modify and I am not sure if it gets packaged in the .exe, as well. When I tested the produced .exe it reads the values I have initially put in the app.config.

I have tried setting the "Copy to Output Directory" option to "Copy always" but that didn't change anything. The "Build action" is set to "None".

How can I set it so that everything EXCEPT the app.config is packaged inside that .exe file, so that the user can change values?

Comment: There's no `app.config` any more.  Just delete it. Put any settings in `appsettings.json` or any other filer or configuration storage you may want. Even `appsettings.json` isn't a hard requirement, it's only a default name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, what do you mean "There's no `app.config` any more"? Because stated like that it kinds of dismisses reality. :) What are the differences and benefits in using `appsettings.json` over `app.config`?

Comment: There's no app.config any more. That's the reality. The values there aren't used or even read in any way. If you get *any* kind of values, they probably come from the generated Settings.cs defaults - which, by extension, means you converted an existing .NET Old project into .NET Core. The new configuration system is [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). `appsettings.json` is only the default used by the default host builder. You can easily add other files, other sources

Comment: The configuration system reads and merges values from *all* sources. Providers added later in the chain can override values read from earlier providers. This means you can publish your own json, xml or ini file and have the application read it. If you check the [xml format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#xml-configuration-provider) supported by the file provider, it's nothing like the old app.config format.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'll take a look at your links but I created this project as a .Net Core Console Application, I haven't converted it from an old .Net project and I have added an app.config no problem. When I publish this project, I don't know if this should be so but, in the output I get an app.config and a <myExeName>.dll.config. If I change the values in the app.config, nothing happens. If I change the values in the .dll.config file - they are reflected, i.e. the program reads the new values.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's [a problem with single-file](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7491) bundles and the base path defaults to the folder where the `.exe` bunlde is unpacked instead of the location of the `.exe`. Even with appsettings.json, you have to use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` to find the host file's (original exe's) path. With the .NET Core config system, that's just annoying and you have to pass the full path to the setting files.

Comment: *How* did you add the app.config and how do you read it though? Simply adding one to a new Winforms object creates an empty file `App1.config` and no `Settings.cs` file. The generated file is empty too. Are you using ConfigurationManager to read from it? In that case you may be able to use [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.8#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_OpenExeConfiguration_System_String_) with the host's path

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I added it as `Right click on project > Add > New File > Config (I don't remember exact name)`  and, yes, I am using ConfigurationManager, I thought that was the standard way?

Comment: Not any more. I repeat, `.config` files aren't used in .NET Core. You can read it only because you *explicitly* load it through ConfigurationManager. Given the manual steps and the trouble, it's not worth doing this any more. With the new system you'd get multiple sources, DI, logging etc out of the box, while the config files would be a *lot* smaller

Comment: That json file contains only what you want though. You can have different files per environment, you can combine them with *other* sources, including the command line, database and environment variables. At the end of the process, you can retrieve values without knowing where they came from. You can easily use strongly-typed config classes. Doing *that* with app.config was no trivial task. In the end, you have to do the same manual work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, fair enough. I will switch. Thank  you for everything! :)

Comment: Besides, all .NET Core packages that want some type of configuration expect to use the .NET Core config system, and even provide helper functions for it. You'll have to add support for it at some point. And did I mention database sources? Think *centralized, easily editable* configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Short version***

.NET Core doesn't use `app.config`, you'll have to upgrade to the new config system or manually manage the files.

1. Add `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` to the `App1.config` file to keep it out of the bundle.
2. Manually add a `MyApp.exe.config` file with the production settings and add `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>` to have it published to the `Publish` directory. Transformations won't run, so make sure it contains everything that's needed.
3. Finally load the file explicitly to avoid a bug in the application's base path resolution

```
var hostFile=Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(hostFile+".config");
```

To load the published file, as if it were any other file

---

.NET Core 3, even for Windows Forms, doesn't use `app.config`. .NET Core's configuration system is described in [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and despite the name, applies to every .NET Core application. It's far more powerful too, loading configuration from multiple sources, including files (even INI), databases, Azure or AWS setting stores etc.

Adding an `Application Configuration File` to a new Windows Forms project, both in VS 2019 and the command line creates an `App1.config` file with no special meaning as far as VS or .NET Core are concerned. Creating an `AppName.exe.config` requires actually creating a new `AppName.exe.config` file with the production settings.

The only way to read an Old-style `.config` file is to explicitly load it with [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.8#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_OpenExeConfiguration_System_String_). This simply loads the file and parses it. One could pass any file path, or specify a ConfigurationUserLevel which simply resolves to a file location based on the executable's base directory.

*And here's where the trouble starts. There's [a bug.](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7491)*

With Single-file executables, all files are bundled in a single host file with the `.exe` extension. When that file runs for the first time, it unpacks its contents to `AppData\Local\Temp\.net\`, in a new folder named for the application. [By design](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/686205657ace53b3e6d568cb098be302f6974956/accepted/single-file/design.md), the application's base directory should be the *host's* path, where the single .exe is. Unfortunately, [there's a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7491) and the base directory remains the location of the bundle and the `.dll` that's actually run by the host.

That's why

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath
```

returns `C:\Users\myUser~1\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\ConsoleApp_NetCore\nk5sdmz5.ym1\ConsoleApp_NetCore.dll.config` and I'd bet `AppContext.BaseDirectory` returns `C:\Users\myUser~1\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\ConsoleApp_NetCore\nk5sdmz5.ym1\`

The *workaround* for this is to retrieve the host's path and load the settings file explicitly. This means we can now use any file name. If we keep the old convention of naming the file `appname.exe.config`, we can just append `.config` to the host's full path:

```
var hostFile=Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(hostFile+".config");
```

This has to be done with the .NET Core File provider too.

Comment: Did you mean `Path.GetDirectoryName`?

Comment: By Jove I just now read your entire answer and you are a technical genius! Thank you very, very much for the detailed explanation and all your help! :)

Comment: @J.Doe no, I run into this myself and ended up just stuffing everything into `APPDATA` because I had no time. Then someone else asked about the problem, I googled, blah, blah, I found that issue, facepalmed, started fixing my own code etc. Painful lesson

Comment: I don't understand - in MSDN I see a `Path.GetDirectoryName` method nad `Path.GetDirectory` whines there's no such thing. But I also am not sure what you mean by ".NET Core File provider", so maybe I'm missing a NuGet package.

Comment: @J.Doe that's just a typo. Googling and answering at the same time can have unintended consequences

Comment: Oh, OK. Because your previous comment started with "no" I thought you meant it wasn't supposed to be `Path.GetDirectoryName` like I asked in my first comment to your answer. :)

Comment: Uhhh, just to point out - in your current code you are just passing the directory name + ".config" as the parameter for the full file path. I'd advise something like `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Replace(".exe", ".dll.config")` or just `Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\app.config"`. If I could ask you to point me towards a resource that explains the difference between "app.config" and "myApp.dll.config" I'd be even more grateful! :)

Comment: Separate point - although the code should, theoretically work fine and you are right it'd be better to migrate to .jsons, my program doesn't load values from either config, after I explicitly set it. :(

Answer (score 2):

You should mark the file as `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` in the project settings.

https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7738
https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/single-file/design.md#build-system-interface

Comment: That's great, thanks! But now the program won't read from the .config file, at all. Neither from the "app.config" nor from the "<exeName>.dll.config" that popped up in the same folder as the .exe.

Comment: UPDATE: using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath` I get `C:\Users\myUser~1\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\ConsoleApp_NetCore\nk5sdmz5.ym1\ConsoleApp_NetCore.dll.config`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for a standalone exe. 
In my .csproj file I added this which created the myProgramName.dll.config upon build.

```
<ItemGroup>
 <None Update="App.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
 </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

And in my C# console app code (dot net core 3.1.0) I added this.

```
// requires using System.Configuration;
string programName = "myProgramName"; 
var sourceHostFile = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\" + programName + @".dll.config";
Console.WriteLine("sourceHostFile is: " + sourceHostFile);
// to load yourProgram.dll.config
// With Single-file executables, all files are bundled in a single host file with the .exe extension. 
// When that file runs for the first time, it unpacks its contents to AppData\Local\Temp\.net\, in a new folder named for the application
var targetHostFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
// ignore when in debug mode in vs ide
if (sourceHostFile != targetHostFile)
{
File.Copy(sourceHostFile, targetHostFile, true);
}
Console.WriteLine("targetHostFile is: " + targetHostFile);
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
Console.WriteLine("password from config is: " + password);
// end of poc
```